# I cann't find "Image Asset" for fixing icons in Android Studio 4.2 while working with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, icons, flutter-layout

[image]

Project -> Android -> app -> src -> main -> res and than right click on res

Comment: Open the `android` folder in a different Android Studio so that it can detect that its an Android project not Flutter.

Comment: thanks for the hint, it reallyhelped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You can't use android assets as icons inside your flutter app!***

But

do you want to create a new one from right click

go as follows

in android studio go to

```
Tools > Flutter > Open Android Module in Android Studio
```

then select new window

then it opens from android studio as a new window
then go to

```
File > Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

wait for it is done :)

then go

```
app > res
```

then

```
Right click > new
```

Updated with as you want !

Answer (score 1):

Open Android version in another window ( it will take some time) then right-click on **res** and click **New** and then click on **Image** **assets**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muRaN.jpg)
You can see by this image :

Comment: You can ask any doubt regarding flutter ..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open Android version. It will take some time to open. Click right button. Click new. You will find Image Asset.